# Find nodes in Neo4j that are at the end of all paths and not in another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are in a POC for Neo4j.  The use case is a dashboard where we only bring back opportunities for a seller that they are qualified for and have not already taken an action on. Currently there are 3 criteria and we are looking to add two more.  The corresponding SQL is 3 pages so we are looking at a better way as when we add the next criteria, 2 more nodes paths in Neo, will be a bear in SQL.  When I run the query below I get back a different amount of rows than the SQL. the buys returned must be at the end of all 3 paths and not be in the 4th. I hope you can point out where I went wrong. If this is a good query then I have a data problem.

Here is the query:

```
//oportunities dashboard
MATCH (s:SellerRep)-[:SELLS]->(subCat:ProductSubCategory)<-[:IS_FOR_SUBCAT]-(b:Buy)
MATCH (s:SellerRep)-[:SELLS_FOR]->(o:SellerOrg)-[:HAS_SELLER_TYPE]->(st:SellerType)<-[:IS_FOR_ST]-(b:Buy)
MATCH (s:SellerRep)-[:SELLS_FOR]->(o:SellerOrg)-[:IS_IN_SC]->(sc:SellerCommunity)<-[:IS_FOR_SC]-(b:Buy)
WHERE NOT  (s:SellerRep)-[:PLACED_BID]->(:Bid)-[:IS_FOR_BUY]->(b:Buy)
AND s.sellerRepId = 217722 and b.currBuyStatus = 'Open'
RETURN b.buyNumber, b.buyDesc, st.sellerType, sc.communtiyName, subCat.subCategoryName+' - '+subCat.desc as sub_cat
```

If it helps, here is the data model:
[POC Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuwTP.png)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A `WHERE` clause only filters the immediately preceding `MATCH` clause.

Since you placed your `WHERE` clause after the third `MATCH` clause, the first 2 `MATCH` clauses are not bound to a specific `SellerRep` or `Buy` node, and are therefore bringing in more `ProductSubCategory` and `SellerType` nodes than you intended.

The following query is probably closer to what you intended:

```
MATCH (s:SellerRep)-[:SELLS]->(subCat:ProductSubCategory)<-[:IS_FOR_SUBCAT]-(b:Buy)
WHERE s.sellerRepId = 217722 AND b.currBuyStatus = 'Open' AND NOT (s:SellerRep)-[:PLACED_BID]->(:Bid)-[:IS_FOR_BUY]->(b:Buy)
MATCH (s)-[:SELLS_FOR]->(o:SellerOrg)-[:HAS_SELLER_TYPE]->(st:SellerType)<-[:IS_FOR_ST]-(b)
MATCH (o)-[:IS_IN_SC]->(sc:SellerCommunity)<-[:IS_FOR_SC]-(b)
RETURN b.buyNumber, b.buyDesc, st.sellerType, sc.communtiyName, subCat.subCategoryName+' - '+subCat.desc as sub_cat
```

NOTE: Your second and third `MATCH` clauses both started with `(s:SellerRep)-[:SELLS_FOR]->(o:SellerOrg)`. I simplified the same logic by having my third `MATCH` clause just start with `(o)`. Hopefully, you actually intended to force both clauses to refer to the same `SellerOrg` node.